# Jquery- UI Toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

On the http://jqueryui.com/toggle/ there is nice example which shows how to use toggle method for animations, it even provides arbitrary method to pass type of animation as parameter.

This is less complex example (based on toogle), but it does not work. I have added second button that should do hardcoded animation (runeffect2). Basically it should do animation right there without calling the method... but it does not work. I just cant figure out why...

```
</style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    // run the currently selected effect
    function runEffect() {
      // get effect type from
      var selectedEffect = $( "#effectTypes" ).val();

      // most effect types need no options passed by default
      var obj = {};

      // run the effect
      $( "#effect" ).toggle( selectedEffect, obj, 500 );
    };

    // set effect from select menu value
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      runEffect();
      return false;
    });
    $( "#buttonn" ).click(function() {
        var options = {};

      $( "#effect" ).toggle( "Explode", options, 500 );
      //return false;
    });

  </script>
```

I have placed full non working solution on fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xTfED/

Comment: "Explode" in lowercase works: http://jsfiddle.net/xTfED/1/

Comment: Cant believe how blind I am... thanks!!!!

Comment: Dont feel bad Wex, I have asked questions where I have forgotten things like forgetting the "." in $.ajax